# Can expired orange juice be used in baking

Tags: baking, juice

Wanted to use up expired orange juice in muffins or cake.

Comment: Is it just expired according to the "use by..." date, or is anything detectably wrong with the juice?

Comment: Hello Mary, please note that we can only ask questions about formal food safety. Of course people use expired food all the time, but we cannot make this decision for you, if you want to do it, it is your risk to take. In case your question was about being unsure if the date means it is actually expired, I closed as a duplicate to a question which explains how to interpret dates printed on the package.

Answer (score 1):

"Best by" or "Use by" dates on the vast majority of food products are indicators of quality, not safety.  As long as you don't detect any off flavors that will adversely impact your muffins or cake....bake away.